# Must a ranger use either only a bow or only a sword?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, class

I'm new to [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e), and I'm considering playing a ranger. A ranger picks either archery or dual-wielding, but is a ranger limited to carrying around and using *only* weapons associated with that choice? I'd like my level 1 ranger to be able to pick whether to use a bow or a sword depending on the situation, but I can't tell if that's allowed.

Answer (score 14):

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/ranger.htm): (also in the Players Handbook)

> A ranger is proficient with all simple and martial weapons

That means you are able to use most [weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#tableWeapons) in the book (everything that isn't Exotic).

The ranger's Combat Style ability makes you *better* at using either archery or dual weapons. It doesn't *prevent* you from anything else.

(If you want to switch between a bow and a longsword, you'd be best to take the archery combat style.)

Comment: In fact, I'd recommend carrying a few extra weapons. Since the ranger is good with anything, a couple throwing knives, a one-hand weapon + shield and a two-handed weapon (or two one-hand weapons) open up options.